# LibGdx ShaderProgram for water break my graphic code

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, 2d, shader

I'm making a 2D game in libGDX.
And it's run well, and look like that : [image: Before Shader water]

Now i'm looking for some water renderer, and I've found some amazing stuff : [tutorial](http://rotatingcanvas.com/fragment-shader-to-simulate-water-surface-in-libgdx/), and it's run well.
But, when I renderer sequentially my game then the "water effect", the act of drawing water literally break my graphic like that : [image: After Shader wate]
All block change with other, I've creepy animation. And I can't figure out what is the problem..

I render all my game with spriteBatch.draw(...); and for the water :

```
`//RENDER WATER 
 Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);        
 Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND); 
 texture2.bind(1); // traitement that break the code
 texture3.bind(2); 
 shader.begin(); 
 shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", matrix); 
 shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 1); 
 shader.setUniformi("u_texture2", 2); 
 shader.setUniformf("timedelta", -angle); 
 waterMesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN); 
 shader.end();`
```

In fact, I want to know how to tell LibGdx to simply apply the "water effect" at the end, but does not affect what is already on the screen.

Thx !

Comment: I would guess you apply things in the wrong order or missed some step that restricts to effect to some piece in the tutorial. But you would indeed have to show relevant code for someone to figure that out.

Comment: I render all my game with `spriteBatch.draw(...);` and for the water  : `//RENDER WATER
  Gdx.gl20.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
  texture2.bind(1);
  texture3.bind(2);

  shader.begin();
  shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView",  matrix);
  shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 1);
  shader.setUniformi("u_texture2", 2);
  shader.setUniformf("timedelta", -angle);
  waterMesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
  shader.end();`

Comment: Without the 'texture2.bind(1);
  texture3.bind(2);', it's normal with a black bar a the position of the water. But with this two lines (also with the first only), I have the result I loaded.

Comment: Please use the magic [edit] button. Code is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpriteBatch makes the assumption that the GL state has been left at the defaults, and in this case, you are not leaving the active texture unit as 0 when you bind multiple textures, so SpriteBatch is not using the correct texture for your sprites.

Call `Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);` right before `spriteBatch.begin()` to fix this.